# how to write a function Click() for dynamic created button?

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

Trying to write a simple VCL program for educating purposes (dynamicly created forms, controls etc). Have such a sample code:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TForm* formQuiz = new TForm(this);
    formQuiz->BorderIcons = TBorderIcons() << biSystemMenu >> biMinimize >> biMaximize;
    formQuiz->Position = TPosition::poDesktopCenter;
    formQuiz->Width = 250;
    formQuiz->Height = 250;
    formQuiz->Visible = true;

    TButton* btnDecToBin = new TButton(formQuiz);
    btnDecToBin->Parent = formQuiz;
    btnDecToBin->Left = 88;
    btnDecToBin->Top = 28;
    btnDecToBin->Caption = "Dec to Bin";
    btnDecToBin->Visible = true;
}
```

I wonder how can i write a function for dynamic created button, so it would be called when the button is clicked. In this example i need a 'btnDecToBin->Click();' func but i don't know where should i place it.

Inside '`void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender){}`' ?

I will appreciate any input, some **keywords** for google too.

Comment: Put it inside the TForm1 class.  Don't assume that dynamically generating a method is possible.

Comment: But how can i refer to the button, that is dynamically created on 'formQuiz', which is also dynamically created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do two things, you could either create an action and associate it with the button, or you could make a function like so:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::DynButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    // Find out which button was pressed:
    TButton *btn = dynamic_cast<TButton *>(Sender);

    if (btn)
    {
        // Do action here with button (btn).
    }
}
```

You bind it to the button instance by setting the OnClick property `btnDecToBin->OnClick = DynButtonClick` please  note that the function is inside the form Form1. This will work due to the nature of closures (compiler specific addition). The problem comes if you delete `Form1` before `formQuiz` without removing the reference to the click event. In many ways it might be a more clean solution to use an Action in this case.

**Edit:** On other way to do this, if you have a standard layout for your quizforms, you could make a custom `TQuizForm` class inheriting from `TForm`. In this way you wouldn't have to bind the event each time you create the form.

Comment: // Find out which button was pressed:
    TButton *btn = dynamic_cast<TButton *>(Sender);

That won't tell you which button was pressed, it'll just be NULL if Sender is something /other than/ a TButton*

Comment: Well in that case no button was pressed right? :) Besides if you add this function as the OnClick event for objects that are not buttons, I guess you would handle that in code. The line I mentioned does indeed tell you which object triggered the event, and in case of buttons it will tell you which button did so. The answer is as far as I can tell correct.

Answer (score 1):

all buttons have the normal "events" you just need to reference them to the method you will deal with the event.

example:

```
...    
btnDecToBin->OnClick = &Test;
```

-- and add a additional method to .cpp

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Test(TObject *Sender)
{

   TButton *btn = dynamic_cast<TButton *>(Sender);

    if (btn->name == "your_button_name"){         
    // Do action here with button (btn).     
    }

}
```

and on .h

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Test(TObject *Sender);
```

reference the button either by the tag or name. I usually use a array of buttons that I create dynamically. ALWAYS sanity check your "sender" by casting it. There are other ways to hack info from the object but they are a path to heartache... LOL.