# array of TRectangles in FMX

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

I am trying to extend [the code from this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53862685/move-trectangle-with-mouse-fmx-win32/53866056#53866056) from using one TRectangle to using multiple rectangles that can be added at runtime. In that example the code to click on and drag applies only to that one TRectangle `Rectangle1`.  I need to make it more general so it works on any recangle I add to the form (the rectangles won't be there at design time).  I found [this code to create a custom class](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/164159/borland-c-builder-6-creating-new-objects-how) and it works fine to create new rectangles.  I can assign methods that run when they are clicked on but i think it is the wrong path to go down due to being a separate class from `TForm1`...and many of the data points i need to make my code work are from `TForm1` (positions etc.).

In short, i want to be able to add TRectangles at runtime and run code on normal events (when rectangle is clicked on, mouseup etc.) for that specific rectangle.

Not sure where to start...but first I think i need to know how to make an array of controls that can be accessed something like this:

```
rectangles[i]->Position->X = ...
```

And then have events that fire when the rectangles are clicked on that can act on that i'th rectangle:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::rectsMouseDown(TObject *Sender, TMouseButton Button,
      TShiftState Shift, float X, float Y){
rectangles[i]->Position->X = ....
rectangles[i]->Position->Y = .....
}
```

**UPDATE 1**:  I am able to create a vector of TRectangles and manipulate them through the vector.  Now, how can i access their events to run code (e.g. OnClick)?  Here is what i have so far:

```
#include <vector>  // in my cpp file

std::vector<TRectangle*> myRects; // in my cpp file outside of any function so it is global

void __fastcall TForm1::Button3Click(TObject *Sender)
{
TRectangle *R = new TRectangle(this);
R->Parent = this;
R->Position->X = 20 + 5*myRects.size(); // slightly offset them in space
R->Position->Y = 20;
R->Tag = myRects.size()+1;  // i think this is how i will tell them apart
myRects.push_back(R);
}
```

I can move a rectangle like this:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button4Click(TObject *Sender)
{
myRects[1]->Position->X = 50;  // this moves rectangle number 2.
myRects[1]->Position->Y = 50;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**:  With Remy's direction i have it working now!  I added `R->OnClick = &myRectOnClick;` to my `Button3Click` method right above the `push_back`. Then i added the following method to my TForm1.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::myRectOnClick(TObject *Sender)
{
 if (TRectangle *Re = dynamic_cast<TRectangle *>(Sender)) {  // make sure result of cast is not null
  ShowMessage("Rectangle " + IntToStr(Re->Tag));  // Tag is how i know which rectangle i'm dealing with
 }
}
```

**UPDATE 3**:  Not sure if this should be a new question...but I added a `PopupMenu1` that i want to invoke with right-click on the rectangles.  I incorporated it with `R->PopupMenu = PopupMenu1` in the`Button3Click` code. The `MenueItem1Click` event just does a `ShowMessage` displaying the rectangles number (`currentR`).  Well, the global int `currentR` for the rectangle doesn't get set when i just right-click on a rectangle.  I have to left-click first, and then right-click for `currentR` to get set to this rectangles tag.  Below is my code for the mouse down event on a rectangle - seems like it should always set `currentR` to the present rectangle regardless of left or right click.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::myRectOnMouseDown(TObject *Sender, TMouseButton Button,
      TShiftState Shift, float X, float Y)
{
if (TRectangle *Re = dynamic_cast<TRectangle *>(Sender)) {  // make sure result of cast is not null
   currentR = Re->Tag; // which rectangle
   if (Button == 0) {  // left mb
   fMouseIsDown = true;
   fMouseInRectAtClick.X = X;
   fMouseInRectAtClick.Y = Y;
   }
 }
}
```

For clarity here is my latest version of the `Button3Click` code that places a new rectangle on the form:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button3Click(TObject *Sender)
{
TRectangle *R = new TRectangle(this);
R->Parent = this;
R->Position->X = 20 + 5*myRects.size();
R->Position->Y = 20;
R->Tag = myRects.size()+1;
R->OnMouseDown = &myRectOnMouseDown;
R->OnMouseUp = &myRectOnMouseUp;
R->OnMouseMove = &myRectOnMouseMove;
R->PopupMenu = PopupMenu1; // to get a popup menu 
myRects.push_back(R);
}
```

Comment: Any decent tutorial/book on C++ will cover the topic of arrays. In this case, you likely need a dynamic array. So use C++'s standard `std::vector` container, or C++Builder's `DynamicArray` or `T(Object)List` class.

Comment: Ok, i can create a new rectangle and add it to my vector.  How do i specify a function to run when it is clicked on?  See UPDATE 1 above.

Comment: See [array of buttons dynamically made each with his independent click action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274708/) and [how to write a function Click() for dynamic created button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116959/).

Comment: Ok, thank you Remy.  Those two links tie it up nicely!

Comment: I added a popup menu invoked on right-click on rectangle.  Having problem as described in UPDATE 3 (let me know if this should be new question).

Comment: Yes, it is a new question. But in any case, your approach to identify which rectangle invokes the popup menu is completely wrong. Inside a menu item's `OnClick` event, use the `TPopupMenu.PopupComponent` property to access the `TRectangle` that was right-clicked on

Comment: That was it, thank you.  I [used this code](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Menus_TPopupMenu_PopupComponent.html) to get to my `TRectangle` component.